# DOMException: Sanitized MIME type image/svg+xml not supported on write

Tags: javascript, svg, clipboard, mime

i want to add a svg file that I generated as a string to the clipboard using javascript. however it seems that svgs are unsupported? does anyone know how to work around this?

```js
function setClipboard(svg) {
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
        if (result.state === 'granted') {
            var blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
            console.log(blob);
            var item = new ClipboardItem({'image/svg+xml': blob});
            navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(function() {
            }, function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
        }
    }); 
}

svg = `<?xml version='1.0'?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN''http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style='fill-opacity:1; color-rendering:auto; color-interpolation:auto; text-rendering:auto; stroke:black; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-miterlimit:10; shape-rendering:auto; stroke-opacity:1; fill:black; stroke-dasharray:none; font-weight:normal; stroke-width:1; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-size:12px; stroke-dashoffset:0; image-rendering:auto;' width='1120' height='760' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><!--Generated--><defs id='genericDefs'/><g style='stroke-linecap:round; stroke-width:4; fill:none'><line x1='200.0' y1='680.0' x2='200.0' y2='80.0'/><line x1='200.0' y1='680.0' x2='880.0' y2='680.0'/><line x1='200.0' y1='80.0' x2='190.0' y2='100.0'/><line x1='200.0' y1='80.0' x2='210.0' y2='100.0'/><line x1='880.0' y1='680.0' x2='860.0' y2='670.0'/><line x1='880.0' y1='680.0' x2='860.0' y2='690.0'/></g><g style='stroke-linecap:round; stroke-width:4; fill:none'><line x1='200.0' y1='180.0' x2='800.0' y2='680.0'/><line x1='200.0' y1='180.0' x2='500.0' y2='680.0'/><path d='M 250.0 480.0 Q350.0 680.0, 580.0 130.0'/><path d='M 380.0 180.0 Q480.0 410.0, 680.0 200.0'/></g><g style='stroke-width:0;' fill = 'black' font-size = '20' font-family='Arial' alignment-baseline='hanging'></g></svg>`

setClipboard(svg);
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Currently, this only works in Chrome >=87 with the `chrome://flags/#raw-clipboard` flag set.